# Java instanceof with changing objects

Tags: java, dynamic, instanceof

I need a method where i could pass on a parameter which i assume would be a Class (not sure though) and in that method, instanceof would be used to check if x is an instance of the passed Class.

How should i do that? I tried a few things but none worked.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

How about this:

```
public boolean checker(Object obj) {
    return obj instanceof SomeClass;
}
```

or if `SomeClass` needs to be a parameter:

```
public boolean checker(Object obj, Class someClass) {
    return someClass.isInstance(obj);
}
```

or if you want the instance to be `someClass` and NOT an instance of a subclass of `someClass`:

```
public boolean checker(Object obj, Class someClass) {
    return someClass.equals(obj.getClass());
}
```

Comment: for completeness, both `obj` and `someclass` have to be checked if `null` or not

Comment: @HussainAl-Mutawa - I disagree.  In the absence of a specification, the correct behaviour would be to let a NullPointerException occur when the methods are called with bad (i.e. `null`) arguments.

Comment: Note the difference between the 2nd and 3d variants: 3d returns true only when the type of `obj` is strictly `someclass`, and 2nd returns true also when `obj.getClass()` extends or implements `someclass`.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov - yes ... that's what I said.

Answer (score 16):

Use [`Class.isInstance(Object)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance%28java.lang.Object%29).